# How to color a whole float, like table, using KOMAScript document class?

Tags: floats, color, captions, koma-script

I managed to get a whole float coloured including its whole caption using the standard article class. But when using KOMA-Script it doesn't work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
{\arrayrulecolor{red}
\begin{table}\color{red}
\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  7C0 & hexadecimal \\
  3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  11111000000 & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  1984 & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{Some table}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to print the caption of this table in red, you can add `\setkomafont{caption}{\color{red}}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\color{red}}` inside the `table` environment.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, that works. So, I guess KOMA-Script overrides the caption(label) colors for some reason. That is a bit annoying. Would have be better they set them to inherit by default, I guess. Or is there another way to make KOMA-script do that?

Comment: I don't think this is possible that easily. However, if you need table environments like this frequently throughout your document, you might consider defining a new environment for them so you don't have to retype the code over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default font elements `caption` and `captionlabel` are set to `\normalfont`. If you want to use the current color you could add

\addtokomafont{caption}{\color{.}}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\color{.}}

and maybe `\arraycolor{.}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\color{.}}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\color{.}}
\arrayrulecolor{.}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  7C0 & hexadecimal \\
  3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  11111000000 & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  1984 & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}\color{red}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  7C0 & hexadecimal \\
  3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
  11111000000 & binary \\
  \hline \hline
  1984 & decimal \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some table}
\end{table}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `\centering` is a switch.